algorithm needed for historical backups
I back up important paths from my PC each day with an automated process that creates zip files. On the 20 terabyte drive I can have close to three years worth. Each weekend I make a VHDX backup of my PC hard disk. There are 22 backups kept with the oldest falling off each time.
I would like to change these and not keep so many. I might keep backups within the last few days but begin spacing them out to 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32 months old.
Distributing a daily backup process out over these spans of time is probably easy but I have yet to put thought work into it. Ideas would be appreciated for an algorithm.

Something simple is probably your best bet: Daily backups are kept for 1 month, Weekly backups are kept for a year and Yearly backups are kept forever.
There is no reason to do multiple backups, if a backup is taken on Monday it's a "Weekly" otherwise its a "Daily" unless it's taken on the last day of the year in which case its a "Yearly".

@DavidT: if you posted that as an answer, it's worth an up-vote to me. KISS it.

Whenever a daily backup finishes, check which older backups you have and if there are more backups than you want to keep, delete the superfluous ones. That's trivial, so I don't see any problem where we could help you with here. Voting to close ("needs details or clarity").  I am happy to revoke my close vote when you present us a real problem .

I'm no doubt making it more complex than necessary. Cannot visualize it so cannot code it.

You might be interested in how other backup tools do this. E.g. the Borg-Backup prune command can be used to thin out the backup frequency over time. You can think of its algorithm of defining criteria for multiple bins, and then keeping the latest backup falls within a bin. Bins are filled in order, so won't be left empty. Of course, Borg deduplicates data across backups, so deleting a backup often only frees up only 100MB or so.

Something simple is probably your best bet, for example:

Daily  backups are kept for 1 month,
Weekly backups are kept for a year and
Yearly backups are kept forever.

For this use case, it is not necessary to do multiple backups, if a backup is taken on Monday it's a "Weekly", otherwise its a "Daily", unless it's taken on the last day of the year in which case its a "Yearly".
That schedule is only an example, create something similar that works for you. Finally you will need some kind of alerting/verification/test restore to ensure you know (in a reasonable amount of time), if one of the backup fails - so that you can redo/ensure a good backup is available.
